# How to keep gemset on changing tab in mac terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, terminal, rvm, gemset

I am trying to keep the gemset of rvm when I create a new terminal tab on Mac OS. I know that I can set a gemset as a default but I don't want to do this.

Maybe someone can help me with this question.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a ruby-version file with rvm. In terminal, go to project directory and run:
`rvm --ruby-version use 1.9.3@my_app`

Here `1.9.3` is your current ruby version and `my_app` is gemset name.

Comment: I have tried this and it's not working. I know how to use and how to create new gemset but I don't know how to keep this value in a project.